# Question on operator+ overload of random access iterator, in template

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, overloading, operator-keyword

I would like to overload the "+" operator of iterator in list class, something like

```
list<double>::iterator operator+(const list<double>::iterator& it, int n)
```

This works well. However, when I try to implement it as template, like

```
template<class T>
typename list<T>::iterator operator+(const typename list<T>::iterator& it, int n)
```

I got error msg like,

```
no match for 'operator+' in 'it + small_index'
```

can't figure out the reason...

The code is attached below,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const list<T>& l)
{
  typename list<T>::const_iterator i = l.begin();
  for (;i!=--l.end();i++)
    os<<*i<<";";
  os<<*i<<endl;
  return os;
}

template<class T> //this is where it goes WRONG.
                  //If don't use template, delete "typename", T->double, runs well
typename list<T>::iterator operator+(const typename list<T>::iterator& it, int n)
{
  typename list<double>::iterator temp=it;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    temp++;
  return temp;
}

template <class T>
void small_sort(list<T>& l)
{
  int n = l.size();
  typename list<T>::iterator it = l.begin();
  for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
      //Find index of next smallest value
      int small_index = i;
      for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
      if(*(it+j)<*(it+small_index)) small_index=j;
    }
      //Swap next smallest into place
      double temp = *(it+i);
      *(it+i) = *(it+small_index);
      *(it+small_index)=temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
  list<double> l;
  l.push_back(6);
  l.push_back(1);
  l.push_back(3);
  l.push_back(2);
  l.push_back(4);
  l.push_back(5);
  l.push_back(0);

  cout<<"=============sort the list=============="<<endl;
  small_sort(l);
  cout<<l;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `std::advance` instead of rewriting?

Comment: The title is pretty misleading since list iterators aren't random access. Providing `operator+` for list iterators would encourage use an an inefficient algorithm (which is why the standard doesn't have such an operator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the argument is not deducible in that context.

```
template<class T>
typename list<T>::iterator operator+(const typename list<T>::iterator& it, int n);
```

When you use an iterator there, the compiler would have to generate all possible instantiations of `list` with any given type, and try to match an internal type `iterator` with the argument that you are passing, note that the set of *all types* is actually infinite once you add templates to the mix, as you can instantiate a template with an instantiation of the same template *ad infinitum*.

I recommend that you avoid the problem altogether and use `std::advance` which is the idiomatic way of advancing an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look whether the standard algorithm `std::advance(it, n)` could be used. It's defined in `<iterator>`. It does "the right thing" for any suitable iterator.